# nvidia-450.66 does not install rhel 7.8, 3.10.0-1127.19.1, where to report?

Tags: nvidia

I did a yum update this morning on my server at work, it RHEL 7.8 and was running the previous latest kernel with **NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run**.

It is now running

```
Linux 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 11 19:12:04 EDT 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried installing **NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-450.66.run** and it failed with the following error in `/var/log/nvidia-installer.log`

```
nvidia-installer log file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log'
creation time: Wed Sep  2 11:08:27 2020
installer version: 450.66

nvidia-installer command line:     ./nvidia-installer

Unable to load: nvidia-installer ncurses v6 user interface

Using: nvidia-installer ncurses user interface
-> Detected 128 CPUs online; setting concurrency level to 32.
-> Tagging shared libraries with chcon -t textrel_shlib_t.
-> Installing NVIDIA driver version 450.66.
-> There appears to already be a driver installed on your system (version: 440.82).  As part of
   installing this driver (version: 450.66), the existing driver will be uninstalled.  Are you
   sure you want to continue? (Answer: Continue installation)
-> Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to
   automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later. (Answer: Yes)
-> Install NVIDIA's 32-bit compatibility libraries? (Answer: Yes)
-> Uninstalling the previous installation with /bin/nvidia-uninstall.
   Looking for install checker script at ./libglvnd_install_checker/check-libglvnd-install.sh
   executing: '/bin/sh ./libglvnd_install_checker/check-libglvnd-install.sh'...
   Internal error:

   ERROR: Installation has failed.  Please see the file '/var/log/nvidia-installer.log' for
          details.  You may find suggestions on fixing installation problems in the README
          available on the Linux driver download page at www.nvidia.com.
```

So I reinstalled 440.82 without problem, *I don't really need the latest nvidia at the moment*.

But where is the best place to report something like this (other than here) ?  Along with if you know a fix to this...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error

```
Looking for install checker script at ./libglvnd_install_checker/check-libglvnd-install.sh
   executing: '/bin/sh ./libglvnd_install_checker/check-libglvnd-install.sh'...
   Internal error:
```

for me the problem was in amdgpu driver packages

Comment: Welcome to the site and thank you for your contribution. Please edit your post to explain how you identified the `amdgpu` driver package to be the source of the problem, and what you did to solve it.